# How can I add a debounce to a button using RXJS?

Tags: rxjs

I want to add a timeout/debounce to pagination buttons, so that when you spam the button, it only executes once instead of the spammed times.

My current code is following but does not work:

```
  onNextPage(): void {

    of("dummy").pipe(
      exhaustMap(this.increasePage)
    )

  }

  increasePage() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.page++
      this.onViewPage()
      resolve(true)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the operator here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime

Inserting it before `exhaustMap` should do the job.